# Image always loading placeholder in e-mail template

Tags: image, email-templates, thumbnail

I'm trying to create some fancy e-mail template for the productalert (when a product returns back in stock) in our website, but I'm not able to load the product image, in any method. In the /template/email/productalert/stock.phtml file I've tried:

```
(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(130, 130)
```

using thumbnail/image/small_image 
or

```
$product->getImageUrl()
```

both with or without a `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());` before.

All I get is always the placeholder. Images are loaded correctly in the website.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you check once removing 'thumbnail' with 'image'?

Comment: yes, I tried with thumbnail, image and small_image... No way!